# Issue with OpenFileDialog and InitialDirectory property

Tags: vb.net, winforms, visual-studio-2017

I have two `Buttons` and two `OpenFileDialog`s and I am facing an issue with `InitialDirectory` property. When I choose a file for my first `OpenFileDialog` and then click to choose a file for my second `OpenFileDialog`, I get the same `InitialDirectory` and not the ones I have set!!!

Here is an example of my code...

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim FileDialog As New OpenFileDialog
        Dim Path As String = Nothing

        If Label1.Text IsNot Nothing And My.Computer.FileSystem.FileExists(Label1.Text) Then
            Path = Label1.Text
        Else
            Path = "::{20D04FE0-3AEA-1069-A2D8-08002B30309D}"
        End If

        FileDialog.Title = "Open File Dialog"
        FileDialog.InitialDirectory = Path
        FileDialog.Filter = "Executable (*.exe)|*.exe"
        FileDialog.RestoreDirectory = True

        If FileDialog.ShowDialog() = DialogResult.OK Then
            Label1.Text = FileDialog.FileName
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
        Dim FileDialog As New OpenFileDialog
        Dim Path As String = Nothing

        If Label2.Text IsNot Nothing And My.Computer.FileSystem.FileExists(Label2.Text) Then
            Path = Label2.Text
        Else
            Path = "::{20D04FE0-3AEA-1069-A2D8-08002B30309D}"
        End If

        FileDialog.Title = "Open File Dialog"
        FileDialog.InitialDirectory = Path
        FileDialog.Filter = "Executable (*.exe)|*.exe"
        FileDialog.RestoreDirectory = True

        If FileDialog.ShowDialog() = DialogResult.OK Then
            Label2.Text = FileDialog.FileName
        End If
    End Sub
```

Comment: Can you tell us the content of the `FileName` variable in each case, please?

Comment: There's a couple of things jumping right out at me. First, do you know the difference between a file and a folder? Why are you setting the directory to a file and not a folder? Second, why are you trying to set a filename as `::{20D04FE0-3AEA-1069-A2D8-08002B30309D}` which is an illegal filename....

Comment: Ah yes, the filname variable could be a foldername variable, that's confusing if true.

Comment: @JayV: In both cases is a path of a different executable file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I found what was wrong...

I just had to set the `Path` variable like this `Path = IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(Label1.Text)` and not like this `Path = Label1.Text`. Because the first one gets file's directory path (which is required) and the second one gets file's path. And I was using the second one...